# about cocos2d CCAnimate. How start to reverse animation from just stopped frame?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, reverse

Do you know how animation reverse from stoped frame?

ex> animation frames are 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5

if I touch at 3 frame then animate 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1

if I touch at 4 frame then animate 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1

mh... Is there no way using CCAnimate class?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    //Here "numbers" is your Animation Sprite
    //Get display frame of the sprite
    CCSpriteFrame *currentFrame = [numbers displayFrame];
    GLuint index = currentFrame.texture.name;

    //Use this index to determine current frame's index
    //Beware!!! As I know it will not return a zero based index, so check it out with an output

    /*

    NEXT :

        - Now you know the current frame index, let's say it is 3
        - Re-order your spriteFrames like 3->2->1 (You have new spriteFrames array)
        - CCAnimation with this spriteFrames array
        - CCAction with this CCAnimation
        - Run the Action!!! There, your reversed animation.

    */

}
```